# Parse.com fetch collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I'm new to Parse.com, and I want to ask, how display all items from collection. This is my code:

```
    var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");

    var TestCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
        model: User
    });

    var collection = new TestCollection(); 

    collection.fetch({
        reset: false, 
        success: function(collection) {
                 document.write('<h1>' + "Users:<br>" + '</h1>');
                 document.write('<table><tr>');
                 document.write('<td>User name</td>');
                 document.write('<td>Email</td></tr>'); 
                 collection.each(function(user) {                   
                 document.write('<tr><td>'+user.get('username')+'</td>');                
                 document.write('<td>'+user.get('email')+'</td>');
                  document.write('</tr></table>');    
    });
  },
  error: function(collection, error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

In this way, I got all items, but the webpage always reload without stop. Help please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) is not a method to use here.

Comment: Teemu, thanx. How can I display in the page my items?

Comment: Please follow "See also" links at the linked MDN page.

Comment: Sorry, but don't understand what do you mean?Where is MDN page?

Comment: Scroll down the page I've linked in my first comment until you can see "See also" links ...

Answer (score 0):

Once you've fixed up the `document.write()` issues, you'll also need to be aware that the `User` (and `Role` and `Installation`) classes are special in Parse.

To query them, you can't do it the way you have. Delete the line where you're extending with "User" as that won't work.

Change your collection to the following:

```
var TestCollection = Parse.Collection.extend({
   model: Parse.User
});
```

The way you have done it is correct for any classes you create, but you have to use the inbuilt definitions for the inbuilt Parse classes.

Comment: Thanx, Timothy!I read this before, but I thought it didn't matter. Because I wrote it worked.